# Can I use Xiaomi Smart Light Switch or other smart switches to control devices from other producers?

Tags: smart-home, smart-plugs, smart-lights

I'm trying to make my home smart and I am still in the first steps.

I have some Yeelight smart bulbs and I want to add some smart plugs to control my old devices and some smart switches to control them all.

The problem is that I cannot find a Xiaomi smart plug that supports European plugs. Can I use any smart plug from other vendors instead?

If yes, how can I control that plug with my Xiaomi switch?

Comment: Hey, Ashkan, welcome to the site!  Have you considered using a European to American plug adapter?  It will be a bit bulky, but you can get adapters on ebay for a dollar or two with shipping.  Obviously, you have to ensure that your appliance is dual voltage (***before*** plugging it in), so if it isn't, that won't work (or will cost a good deal more).

Comment: @anonymous2 Hi. Thanks for reply. Not yet. I was reading about zigbee and it has been said that the protocol let's devices from different companies to work together, but there is always a huge gap between what has been implemented and what is on the paper. So I thought I ask before buying anything :)